# How can I link value of a cell from another sheet according to the text which is already in the another sheet?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I am exporting a report from Quickbooks to Excel in a existing excel workbook. In that workbook a table is already created. I am exporting the report to a new sheet in the same workbook.

Now I need to get the values **FROM sheet A1** B column according to the Name in Column A in (This details are exported from Quickbooks (Names order will change when take another report a day after)) **TO Final report sheet**. In that sheet the names are in order so I can't straightly link the cell.

How do I get the value from sheet A1 to sheet Final Report according to the workers name?

[image: image1] [image: image2]

Comment: It's hard to visualize your problem.  Can you add a screen shot or mockup a simple example within the question?  And in general, pretty much anything is possible.

Comment: Each successive Quickbooks report populates another column on the final report sheet? (Col C shows the data from the current report, Col D the data from the next report, etc.?)  How automated are you looking for?  It's simple to extract the data and put it in the appropriate rows if you use a little manual intervention with each successive report to get it in the correct column.  It starts getting complicated if you want the final report to automatically put stuff in the right column, recognize a new report, etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding as well, but would [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) be what you need?

Comment: Does every report have every name on the final report sheet but just not necessarily in the same order, or could a specific report be missing some of the names?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, [`VLOOKUP`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) will do what you seek.

> You can use the VLOOKUP function to search the first column of a range
>   of cells, and then return a value from any cell on the same row of the
>   range.

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

In your case, using the following formula would achieve the results you described.

`=VLOOKUP(B2,'A1'!$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE)`

If you don't want to see the `#N/A` errors when there is no data available (in the case for Hasitha and Kenton), then use the `IFERROR` function with it like this.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'A1'!$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE),"")`

Place this in `C2` of the `Final` sheet, then copy it down the column.

[image]